# zip command not zipping files in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, zip

The following zip command doesn't not work inside shell

I have the below lines of code to run in a linux shell:

```
zip "${NUMBER}.NEW.zip" test/

zip "${NUMBER}.NEW.${NAME}.zip" test/
```

It gives me the output:

```
adding: test/ (stored 0%)

adding: test/ (stored 0%)
```

when I do an `ls -lrt I` do not see any zip files in the directory test

I tried removing the quotes in the above commands. But the output is still the same.

Comment: Do you have the Zip program installed?

Comment: The zip file is created in the current directory not the `test` directory. Please confirm whether there is a zip file in the current directory or not.

Comment: @UsamaAbdulrehman Why would you think `zip` is not installed? The `adding:` output comes from `zip`.

Comment: Yes @kaylum, you are right. I kind of overlooked that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zip expects file args, and the file type can be a directory.
The example zip command did what it was told: archive 1 directory, not the contents of that dir.
Try -r or --recurse-paths, eg:

```
zip -r $NUMBER.NEW.$NAME.zip test
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of ${NUMBER} and $NAME. If it has a / in it, your zip file got created inside a directory.

For example, if

> ${NUMBER}=2021/

then your file is at **2021/.NEW.$NAME.zip**

and a file with name=.NEW.$NAME.zip will be a hidden file. So you will have to do `ls -a` to see that file.